# Is there a better way to read find HDFS partition folders from the available partition column names?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to automate the way we read the files from HDFS location by various application. Every app has a different base path, but most of them have same partition structure. I am writing a function that would return the folder structure of the partition of my HDFS folder structure. Below is the code I tried,

```
  val TIME_DIMENSION_YEAR = "year"
  val TIME_DIMENSION_DAY = "day"
  val TIME_DIMENSION_MONTH = "month"
  val TIME_DIMENSION_HOUR = "hour"
  val currentPerspective = "event"
  val timeDim = List("hour", "day", "month", "year")
  def getColumnName(perspective: String, dimension: String): String = s"${perspective}_$dimension"

    def applyFilter(year: Option[Int], month: Option[Int], day: Option[Int], hour: Option[Int]): String =
      timeDim.map(getColumnName(currentPerspective, _)).
        foldLeft("/")((acc, dimension) =>
          dimension.split("_")(1) match {
            case TIME_DIMENSION_DAY => s"/${dimension}=${day.getOrElse("*")}${acc}"
            case TIME_DIMENSION_MONTH => s"/${dimension}=${month.getOrElse("*")}${acc}"
            case TIME_DIMENSION_YEAR => s"/${dimension}=${year.getOrElse("*")}${acc}"
            case TIME_DIMENSION_HOUR => s"/${dimension}=${hour.getOrElse("*")}${acc}"
            case _ => null
          }
    )
```

Expected output

```
scala> applyFilter(Some(2020), Some(8), Some(1), None)
res20: String = /event_year=2020/event_month=8/event_day=1/event_hour=*/
```

The problem here is, `List("hour", "day", "month", "year")` cannot be changed and should be in the same order. Else my folder structure would become meaningless. And the code itself is immovable and not robust

Is there a better way to achieve this? I can change input Format/Structure anything to make the code more robust and good standards?

Comment: Why are you trying to partition the folder structure from the smallest to the biggest value for partitioning? You can try the following partitioning scheme event_year=2020/event_month=8/event_day=1/event_hour=*/. Also, can you clarify why do you want to return the folder structure of the partition of the HDFS folder?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was a test run and it depends on the order of the list input that we give. I have the partitions in prod in the exact way you mentioned. I have now updated the question.

Comment: Kindly clarify why do you want to return the folder structure of the partition of the HDFS folder so as to understand your use case and the best approach for it.

Comment: Kindly review the answer and make it as an answer/upvote if it solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks Shrey for your answer. But my problem is not arriving at a solution. I already have a working solution handling different scenarios. What I want is to make it more robust and generic. May be I will add even more details to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
def applyFilter(year: String="*", month: String="*", day: String="*", hour: String="*",currentPerspective:String="default"):String = {
s"/${currentPerspective}_year=${year}/${currentPerspective}_month=${month}/${currentPerspective}_day=${day}/${currentPerspective}_hour=${hour}/"
}
```

Sample output of the function when hours and currentPerspective is not passed to the function:

```
applyFilter(year="2020",month="2",day="12")
```

[image]

Sample output of the function when the hour is not passed:

```
applyFilter(year="2020",month="2",day="12",currentPerspective="event")
```

[image]

Explanation:

When a function is defined, we can state a default value if the parameter value isn't passed. In scala, it is defined using `parameter : DataType="your_value"` and while calling the function specify the parameter using `parameter_name="your_value"` so that the function will use default value only for the parameters where the default value is required.